# Run remote program using PsExec and C# - connected but not working

Tags: c#

I want to run .exe file (installer) at remote computer from local computer. I did it manually using PsExec and Console prompt from my local computer and it is working. No I need to write program in C# to do same thing automaticly.

My code is opening console at remote computer with remote working directory: "C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\Updater" and at line "process.WaitForExit()" it is running forever with no end even if I specify time f.e. "process.WaitForExit(10000)".

Program is not starting my exe.file. I checked it in remote task manager. Adding ""C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\MyInstaller\Installers"" -s -update";" as arguments are essential because my installer needs console prompt.
How to fix it?

```
static string hostname = @"111.111.1.11";
        static string username = "myusername";
        static string password = "mypassword";
        string commandToRunLocal = $@"psexec \\{hostname} -i 1 -w ""C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\Updater"" -u {username} - p {password} cmd";
        string commandToRunRemote = @"DLLConfiguration.exe ""C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\MyInstaller\Installers"" -s -update";

    public string RunRemoteInstaller()
    {
        try
        {
            Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
            startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
            process.StartInfo = startInfo;
            startInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Users\myUserName";
            process.Start();
            process.StandardInput.WriteLine(commandToRunLocal);
            process.StandardInput.Flush();
            process.StandardInput.WriteLine(commandToRunRemote);
            process.StandardInput.Flush();
            process.StandardInput.Close();
            process.WaitForExit();
            string error = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
            string consoleOutput = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

            if (process.ExitCode == 0 && null != process && process.HasExited)
            {
                return process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            }
            else
            {
                return "Error running the command";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Comment: In the PsExec, the command is _C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\Updater_  But I don't see an extension.  What type of file is it? Are you missing the **.bat** or **.exe**

Comment: This path is just a working directory. I perform executing .exe file in the next step.

Comment: **PsExec** is used to perform the command, not open a folder.

Comment: @YoungEddie, did you ever solve this?  I'm running into the same thing --- works if I run PsExec manually, but just seems to hang (until timeout) when I run it from within C#.  In my case, I'm trying to run PsExec through a C# web page.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't open a console on the remote computer.  Open a console on the local computer by using [ProcessStartInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo?view=netframework-4.8) to execute the PsExec on your local machine.  It will execute the command on the remote computer.

In your question, you mention you can open a console on the remote computer, therefore you don't need to use PsExec.  Just execute the command.

Comment: I can open console at remote computer only by using PsExec. I need to code an applicaction to perform everything at distance. Should I write "string commandToRunLocal = PsExec cmd;" then string commandToRunRemote =  psexec \\{hostname} -i 1 -u {username} - p {password} ""DLLConfiguration.exe ""C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\MyInstaller\Installers"" -s -update";" ?